# Event object not taking class C++

Tags: c++

I'm using a C++ game tutorial and I'm having trouble figuring out why my class object that I've created is giving me the error that "Expression must have class type". The object is called "menuEvent" and  when you hover over the variable, on the first line of the brief it says "sf::Event menuEvent" but then on the second line of the brief it says "Error:expression must have class type". It's contradicting itself in the same brief and I can't figure it out. I'm working in Visual Studio 2015 with C++ code. Any help would be extremely appreciated. Here's what I've got;

This piece is from one of my external dependencies documents;

```
namespace sf
{
class Event
{
public:
struct MouseButtonEvent
{
    Mouse::Button button; ///< Code of the button that has been pressed
    int x; ///< X position of the mouse pointer, relative to the left of the owner window
    int y; ///< Y position of the mouse pointer, relative to the top of the owner window
};
};
}
```

Then this piece is from one of my source files;

```
MainMenu::MenuResult MainMenu::HandleClick(int x, int y)
{
std::list<MenuItem>::iterator it;

for (it = _menuItems.begin(); it != _menuItems.end(); it++)
{           
    sf::Rect<int> menuItemRect = (*it).rect;

    if(menuItemRect.contains(sf::Vector2<int>(x,y)))
        {
            return it->action;
        }
}

return Nothing;
}

MainMenu::MenuResult MainMenu::GetMenuResponse(sf::RenderWindow& window)
{
sf::Event menuEvent;

while (true)
{
    window.pollEvent(menuEvent);
    // The above line with menuEvent it reads as being of the sf::Event type

    if (menuEvent.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed)
    {
        //But the below line here when I hover over "menuEvent" it shows that it's of the sf::Event type, but then right below that it says "Error:expression must have class type".
        return HandleClick(menuEvent.MouseButtonPressed.x , menuEvent.MouseButtonPressed.y);
    }

    if (menuEvent.type == sf::Event::Closed)
    {
        return Exit;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you properly included a header that provides `sf::Event` so that's it's visible to the code where you're trying to use it?

Comment: Yes, it's declared in my stdafx.h file, with my other headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared a class called `sf::Event`.

This class declares an inner class called `MouseButtonEvent`.

`MouseButtonEvent` is not a class member. It's an inner class.

You declared an instance of `sf::Event` called "menuEvent":

```
sf::Event menuEvent;
```

Your compiler is failing to compile the following expression:

```
HandleClick(menuEvent.MouseButtonPressed.x,
            menuEvent.MouseButtonPressed.y);
```

The error is because `sf::Event` does NOT have a class member called `MouseButtonPressed` (technically that is not exactly true, but I note that this question does not have a "language-lawyer" tag, so I'm playing it fast-n-loose...)

The expression "menuEvent.MouseButtonPressed" is a reference to a member of `menuEvent`'s class called "MouseButtonPressed".

There is no such class member. `MouseButtonPressed` is an inner class, and not a class member.

The intentions of your code is not clear to me, so I cannot suggest what would be the right syntax for whatever the code is trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still learning when it comes to C++, so could you explain your answer a little bit more? What's the difference between an inner class and a class member? I'm not sure what the language-lawyer tag is, but I've tagged the post with C++? The code is basically trying to return the values of the x and y coordinates of where the mouse is when it's clicked. I'm setting up boundaries for buttons so that when I click inside the buttons' boundaries it does an action. Click Event -> compare against boundaries -> react accordingly. I hope this helps, as I'm completely lost. Thank you

Comment: I just researched around google, and I think I get the difference between the nested classes and the class members, but can class members have their own members? (I'm not sure I'm wording it right) I need MouseButtonPressed to have the two int's "x" and "y", so that I can return them in the "HandleClick" function. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: A class member can be a class, with its own members. So, declare another class with members "x" and "y", then declare a class member that's an instance of the new class.

Comment: Ok, but how would I write the check? Would it be;
    sf::Event menuEvent;
    sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed btnVariable;
    ...
    return HandleClick(menuEvent.btnVariable.x, menuEvent.btnVariable.y)

?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: namespace sf { class Event { ... struct MouseButtonPressed { ... }; MouseButtonPressed btnVariable; }; } ... -- and then pretty much as you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

That did it! Thanks so much for your help Sam Varshavchik.

Here's my final code version;

External Piece;

```
namespace sf {
  class Event
    {
      public:
      struct MouseButtonEvent
        {
          Mouse::Button button; ///< Code of the button that has been pressed
          int x; ///< X position of the mouse pointer, relative to the left of the owner window
          int y; ///< Y position of the mouse pointer, relative to the top of the owner window
        };

      MouseButtonEvent btnVariable;
    }
}
```

Source File Piece;

```
MainMenu::MenuResult MainMenu::HandleClick(int x, int y)
{
  std::list<MenuItem>::iterator it;

  for (it = _menuItems.begin(); it != _menuItems.end(); it++)
   {
    sf::Rect<int> menuItemRect = (*it).rect;

    if(menuItemRect.contains(sf::Vector2<int>(x,y)))
        {
            return it->action;
        }
   }
  return Nothing;
}

MainMenu::MenuResult MainMenu::GetMenuResponse(sf::RenderWindow& window)
  {
    sf::Event menuEvent;

    while (true)
    {

    window.pollEvent(menuEvent);

    if (menuEvent.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed)
      {
        return HandleClick(menuEvent.btnVariable.x , menuEvent.btnVariable.y);
      }

    if (menuEvent.type == sf::Event::Closed)
      {
        return Exit;
      }

    }
  }
```